# Using Images As Buttons Removing White Space

Tags: flash

Hey having trouble in flash, when I make a button and import an image I can't seem to remove the white space in the image and am forced to have a square like button and cant crop out the white and make it unclickable:
-cant post image due to lack of rep sorry so here's a link
http://i58.tinypic.com/2utkahi.png

this is the image I want to make a button, I want to remove the white in flash,( If I make it transparent elsewhere it still seems to include the white) and make it so only the blue part is a click able functioning button. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the type of image, .jpg images will always be untransparent and you will see the square white box, i always use .png with transparency and no white box appears.

Good luck